# What does EMSE mean?

Tags: pcb, components

I'm currently trying to use EAGLE software and I'm trying to import a part called 'LT3022' which is a voltage regulator from Linear Technology.

I've found a CAD library of LT products from element14 and downloaded and added the library.

But in the library the par that I'm looking for is called 'LT3022EMSE'.

It does look like the one I'm looking for but I'm not sure what the EMSE means.

The pin numbers matches the the datasheet so I guess this is the same but I would like to know what the EMSE means anyway.

The image below is a screenshot that mentions EMSE. Looks like there's a lot of variations of EMSE too...

[image: Datasheet Web Page]

Comment: It's just part of the part number.  (it could mean anything... read the spec sheet!)  In this case perhaps just different case styles.

Answer (score 1):

MSE is the 16-lead MSOP package

[image: http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3022fb.pdf]

E or I = grades guaranteed for -40~+125°C temperature range

[image]

(this may be a historical thing where they once had two temperature grades, but now guarantee everything to the same range).

Comment: To expand Spehro's answer, there is nothing universal about the "MSE" suffix on the part number. That's just a naming convention Linear chose to use. Other manufacturers use different suffixes or none at all.